# Finding all differentiable functions with a certain property

Tags: calculus

Find all differentiable functions $f \colon (0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ for which there is a positive real number $k$ such that:
$$ f(x) \cdot f'(k/x) = x, \qquad\text{for all }x > 0. $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In equation 
$$
f(x)f'\left(\frac{k}{x}\right)=x
$$
we make change of variables $k/x\to x$ then for all $x>0$ we get
$$
f\left(\frac{k}{x}\right)f'(x)=\frac{k}{x}
$$
Hence
$$
\left(f(x)f\left(\frac{k}{x}\right)\right)'=f'(x)f\left(\frac{k}{x}\right)+f(x)f'\left(\frac{k}{x}\right)\frac{-k}{x^2}=\frac{k}{x}+x\frac{-k}{x^2}=0
$$
The rest is clear.

Comment: hmm. we get f(x) f(k/x) = C
f(x) = x/f'(k/x)

f'(k/x)/f(k/x) = C/x
ln(f(k/x)) = Clnx + D
f(k/x) = e^D x^C

Is this correct?

Comment: @JohnChang You made two mistakes. The first: you must arrive at $f'(k/x)/f(k/x) = x/C$. The second: even if there were not the first misatke the step from $f'(k/x)/f(k/x) = C/x$ to $\ln(f(k/x)) = Clnx + D$ is incorrect. You need to make change $k/x\to x$ in $f'(k/x)/f(k/x) = C/x$.